# Filter a version number out of a string

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to filter a number out of a string with php preg_match that could look like this (they are versions of a software):

- 1.6.2
- 1.6.2#2
- 1.7

(1.6.2#2 is 2. beta of 1.6.2)

So when there is a string like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 1.6.2# sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Now I want a string that only contains "1.6.2#2"

I tried 
`(\d?[.|#]?)*` but it does not work

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get any errors? Also see: https://regex101.com/r/xU9hH8/1

Comment: Because there are only 3 single strings and not one hole..

Comment: what about version numbers like `1.6beta.7devel`?

Comment: Beta is covered by the #2, so 1.6.2#2 is 2. beta of 1.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regular expression

```
/(\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?(#\d+)?)/
```

Comment: Now it works. BTW I was expecting that you will have a digit after the # all the time. You do not in your example

Comment: Yea there must be a digit behind the #. But it does not work yet https://regex101.com/r/mS9dV8/3

Comment: What do you mean does not work? I can clearly see that match 1 is '1.6.2#' on the right side.

Comment: These are partial matches. You can ignore them.